# CefSharp Use HttpWebRequest cookies

Tags: c#, cookies, httpwebrequest, chromium-embedded, cefsharp

I did not find a special place to ask question so I hope it's ok there. If not I hope you can tell me where to ask.

I do a POST request to be able to login programmatically in C#. So It works, and I get the cookie of my session and the html source code of the page where I'm logged.
As webbrowser is using old internet explorer, I use cefsharp (and soon maybe sharpbrowser) to display the html code with the "LoadHtml()" method.

```
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(getResponse.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        string sourceCode = sr.ReadToEnd();
        chromeBrowser.LoadHtml(sourceCode, "http://www.example.com/");
    }
```

It display my page. But what I want is that if I click any link I'm still logged. Instead when I click I'm redirected to the login page.
How can I give cefsharp the cookie I have so I stay logged in ?

Thanks.

Comment: You can make a `POST` request directly in `CefSharp`, save trying to load cookies, see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cd934267c65f494ceb9ee75995cd2a1ca0954543/CefSharp.Wpf.Example/ViewModels/BrowserTabViewModel.cs#L213

Comment: Still don't really know how to do a detailed post request like I do with httpwebrequest. I don't find things like "CookieContainer", "HttpWebRequest" / "HttpWebResponse" useragent etc ...
It would be simpler if I could just give cefsharp my cookie.

Comment: Then search the source for SetCookie